# can i add a graphics card to this laptop?

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply, gpu

I have an **HP Envy 15 laptop** with specs at http://www8.hp.com/h20195/v2/GetPDF.aspx/c04514967.pdf . I want to add a GPU to the free PCI Express x1. There are two issues, one that the GPU's generally ask for PCI-E 2.0 and the other that the power supply of the laptop is specified as 90W.

Now for the sake of an example lets take up a low end gpu like a GT-610 (specs : http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gt-610/specifications). This asks for a system power supply of 300W.

Is it possible in any way to be able to use this GPU in my laptop ?

Comment: I've seen graphics cards built on PCI-e x1 cards, but they're always going to be low power draw; as I recall there's a current limit on the power connector in the x1 slot.  It's probable your laptop can temporarily draw more than 90W from the battery, but even if you're plugged in, you'll be drawing down the battery if your consumption exceed 90W -- and the laptop's built-in hardware most likely consumes close to half that power supply capacity in steady state operation, so you'd need a GPU card that needs less than, say 40W.  Good luck.

Comment: the specs for this gpu say a max of 29W, then i should be fine with it ? also is it possible to upgrade the laptop from 90W to 300W ?

Comment: Your laptop does not have a PCI Express slot, it has a Mini PCI Express slot. This is an entirely different form factor than the PCIe graphics card you list.

Comment: on doing sudo dmidecode | grep "PCI", i got  : PCI is supported,
 Designation: PCI Express Slot 3,
 Type: x1 PCI Express x1,
 String: PCIExpressx16.

Comment: Bottom line, most likely if you want to be able to upgrade your GPU, you'll probably need to buy a laptop with AT LEAST a full height, half length PCIe-x16 expansion slot or a plain PCI slot with the same clearances -- and enough power capability to drive the card.  Alienware used to make machines like this; I don't know if they still do.  Shell out for a machine like that, however, and most likely you'll then find the built-in graphics are better than anything you can physically fit in the case.  Most decent graphics cards are now full height, full length, double width.

Answer (score -1):

You won't be able to use that specific GPU because:

1. Too high power draw.
2. Uses PCI-E 2.0, way more pins than your laptop provides
3. Space. Unless you want a PCB hanging out of your laptop, it won't fit in.

It's possible that you could find a very low power draw GPU that does fit in the x1 slot, but the GPU will likely be less efficient than your built-in graphics.

Edit:
Again, even x1 cards could be difficult to fit inside the laptop case.